# OpenGL translate object base upon window size

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm trying to create a window where all objects are moved the same relative distance regardless of resolution. I'm setting the viewport to the bounds of -1, 1, 1, -1 and i'm calculating a pixel distance by

```
int number_of_pixels = 10;
float x_pixel_value = (1f / (window.getWidth() / 2)); 
float move_x_value = x_pixel_value * number_of_pixels;

float y_pixel_value = (1f / (window.getHeight() / 2)); 
float move_y_value = y_pixel_value * number_of_pixels;
```

The distance seems to scale correctly but when I move the object in a tiny resolution, it moves much faster compared to if the resolution was bigger.
e.g the object would take 2 seconds to move all the way down the screen at 720p but at 100x100 it would take .3 seconds.

I've tried implementing a frame limiter to make sure that it wasn't lag causing it to move slower but that did nothing.

[Larger resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oa4Fb.png)

[Smaller resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/666id.png)

Comment: I don't get it. If you want to move your objects with a constant window space speed of x pixels/second, it is exactly plausible that a movement speed of 720pixels/2s would result in a movement of 100 pixels taking 0.277777s.

Comment: My goal is to have a window with objects that move at a constant speed regardless of the window size. e.g 
http://prntscr.com/boavg3
Would take the same time to travel as 
http://prntscr.com/boavp4

Comment: Define "constant speed". Speed relative to what? Relative to reality? Relative to number of pixels per second?

Comment: Ok so think of it like a youtube video player playing a video of a cube going from one end of the player to the other. If you scale it down to 100x100 the time taken to get to one end to the other is the same regardless of the scaled size. Thats what im looking to do with these objects. Sorry If I'm confusing you, I'm still figuring out projections.

Comment: If you want a constant time for moving from top to bottom, taking the pixel sizes into account is completely useless. The [-1,1] normalized device space of OpenGL is already providing you a space where you not have to think of pixels. If moving from top to bottom should take 2s, than you should move it with (1- -1)/2 units per second in that space.

Comment: Working in NDC would solve your problem as suggested by @derhass, but if you are confused by NDC, you could also simply consider the percentage of the resolution as your sensitivity. So for a res (W,H) you will use something like 10% of W and 5% of H as the sensitivity. Then you guarantee it will move the same amount regardless of the resolution. eg `sx = W * 0.1f` and `sy = H * 0.2f`. Now always multiply your number of pixels by `(sx, sy)`. Change the factors 10% and 5% to suit the speed. This is however a really bad way to synchronize speed, You should really use Timers for precise timing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a constant value that does not depend on the window dimensions.

The clipping volume does not care about how many pixels there is in each direction; an object at (-1,-1) will always be at the bottom left corner, and (1,1) will always be at the top right corner. The same applies for velocity. If you really want to use window dimensions, call `glOrtho` to change the clipping volume.